# Create Date column from 2 different int columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, time

I ve been wraping my head around on a task which seems fairly easy, but can't get it right.

I've got 2 `int` columns:

- `date` which is like `yyyymmdd`
- `time` which represents the number of seconds since `00:00`

I want to create a date new column in a temp table which is `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`.

I was calculating the time with `TIMEFROMPARTS`. Is there any possible way to do it? Would appreciate any help.

For example, if I have

```
date_int = 20180901
time_int = 32411
```

I would like a new column as a date

```
2018/09/01 09:00:11
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the date to a `datetime` and then add the seconds:

```
select dateadd(second, time_int, cast(cast(date_int as varchar(8)) as datetime))
from (values (20180901, 32411)) v(date_int, time_int);
```

Strictly speaking, the explicit conversion to `datetime` is not necessary, so this also works:

```
select dateadd(second, time_int, cast(date_int as varchar(8)))
from (values (20180901, 32411)) v(date_int, time_int);
```